# How to extract and add the JSON data received as a AJAX response to the HTML select drop down using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've following HTML code :

```
<select id="student" name="student" class="form-control"></select>
```

The jQuery-AJAX function I've written for adding the options to the above HTML select control is as follows :

```
var mod_url = $('#mod_url').val(); 
$.ajax({
      url : mod_url,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      data: {
        'request_type':'ajax',         
      },
      success: function(result, success) { 
        $('#student').html(result);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Error is occured");
      }
    });
```

From PHP file I've received a big array encoded into JSON format(i.e. the result variable from jQuery-AJAX function). For your reference I'm showing below only the first four records from that array. In HTML select control actually I want to show all the elements from this array.

```
[{"id":2,"stud_name":"John Dpalma","stud_address1":"277 Eisenhower Pkwy","stud_address2":"","stud_city":"Edison","stud_state":"New Jersey","stud_country":"USA","stud_zipcode":"07039","stud_email":"abc@gmail.com","created_at":1409739580,"updated_at":1410253832},
{"id":3,"stud_name":"Anthony Gonsalvis","stud_address1":"520 Division St","stud_address2":"","stud_city":"Piscataway","stud_state":"NJ","stud_country":"USA","stud_zipcode":"07201","stud_email":"pqr@gmail.com","created_at":1409740530,"updated_at":1410255590},

{"id":4,"stud_name":"James Bond","stud_address1":"6 Harrison Street, 6th Floor","stud_address2":"Ste-2324","stud_city":"New York","stud_state":"NY","stud_country":"USA","stud_zipcode":"10013","stud_email":"xyz@gmail.com","created_at":1409757637,"updated_at":1412263107},

{"id":9,"stud_name":"Mary Jane","stud_address1":"2112 Zeno Place","stud_address2":"CA","stud_city":"Venice","stud_state":"CA","stud_country":"","stud_zipcode":"90291","stud_email":"utp@gmail.com","created_at":1409908569,"updated_at":1410254282}]
```

In HTML select control I want to set the values in following manner(consider first two records from above array)

```
<select id="student" name="student" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select Store</option>
  <option value="2">John Dpalma, 277 Eisenhower Pkwy, Edison</option>
  <option value="3">Anthony Gonsalvis, 520 Division St, Piscataway</option>
</select>
```

You might have observed from the expected output above that I want to set the value of option as a `id` from array and the text that I want to display is comprising of `stud_name+stud_address1+stud_city`

How should I manage this for all the elements from the JSON data in my code?

Also please guide me in showing the loading option into the select control until the response from PHP comes.

Please provide me some help.

Comment: what is the result you are sending back to the ajax function from the php file?

Comment: @wayzz : The JSON data is the result array came from PHP file. I've encoded using json_encode(); before sending it back to ajax function.

Comment: why don't you echo the select options in your php file and send back the echoed result. Then attach it to your select dropdown using jquery.

Comment: Try to play with jQuery templating

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(result, success) { 
    var $select = $('#student');
    $.each(result, function (i, option) {
        var txt = [option.stud_name, option.stud_address1, option.stud_city];
        if (option.stud_address2)
            txt.splice(2, 0, option.stud_address2);
        $('<option>', {
            value: option.id,
            text: txt.join(', ')
        }).appendTo($select);
    });
},
```

or with `$.map` (slightly more efficient):

```
success: function(result, success) { 
    var options = $.map(result, function (option) {
        var txt = [option.stud_name, option.stud_address1, option.stud_city];
        if (option.stud_address2)
            txt.splice(2, 0, option.stud_address2);
        return $('<option>', {
            value: option.id,
            text: txt.join(', ')
        });
    });
    $('#student').append(options);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just one more query. Can I add if condition in a text attribute as for some of the records from the above array it might be possible that the field stud_address2 will contain blank. So I want to check whether the field stud_address2 is blank or not, if it's not blank only then print it otherwise not. Can I do this? Thanks once again and waiting for your reply eagerly.

Comment: I made an edit, if he will accept, you can see a function which will make a join and skip empty entries.

Comment: ... and if now one of the other fields is empty your code is crap... why didn't you take my changes?

Comment: @Mephiztopheles premature optimization

Comment: @David Fregoli always be far-seeing

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of iterating over the JSON you receive from the server, creating option tags for each record, then appending them to the select element:

```
var response = [{"id":2,"stud_name":"John Dpalma" ... }]

$.each(response, function (index, record) {
  if (!record.stud_address2){
    var stud_address2 = "";
  } else {
    var stud_address2 = record.stud_address2;
  }

  $('<option>', {
    value: record.id,
    text: record.stud_name + ", " + record.stud_address1 + ", " + record.stud_city + ", " + stud_address2
  }).appendTo("#student");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/xznn62az/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just one more query. Can I add if condition in a text attribute as for some of the records from the above array it might be possible that the field stud_address2 will contain blank. So I want to check whether the field stud_address2 is blank or not, if it's not blank only then print it otherwise not. Can I do this? Thanks once again and waiting for your reply eagerly.

Comment: If stud_address2 is blank then you want to print that in addition to stud_address1 or instead of stud_address1?

Comment: I want to print stud_address2 in addition to stud_address1 only if stud_address2 is not blank otherwise not. stud_address1 field will always contains some value. So no issue with it. Please guide me how to make this check and print the value?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP file echo the following in a loop:

```
echo '<option value="">'.$stud_name.', '.$stud_address1.', '.$stud_address2.', '.$stud_city.', '.$stud_state.', '.$stud_country.'</option>';
```

Then attach this result to the select dropdown with jQuery             through the ajax success.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. This checks address 2 and adds it to the options accordingly.

JS code:

```
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    if(result[i]["stud_address2"]==""){
        $('#student').append('<option value="' + result[i]["id"] + '">' + result[i]["stud_name"] + ', ' + result[i]["stud_address1"]+ ', ' +result[i]["stud_city"] +'</option>');}
    else{
     $('#student').append('<option value="' + result[i]["id"] + '">' + result[i]["stud_name"] + ', ' + result[i]["stud_address1"]+ ', '+ result[i]["stud_address2"]+ ', ' +result[i]["stud_city"] +'</option>');
    }
}
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvks9u7p/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var mod_url = $('#mod_url').val(); 
   $.ajax({
         url : mod_url,
         cache: false,
         dataType: "json",
         type: "GET",
         async: false,
         data: {
            'request_type':'ajax',         
         },
         success: function(result, success) { 
           $.each(result,function(index,item){ 
             $label = item.stud_name +', ' + item.stud_address1 +', ' + item.stud_city;
             $('#student').append('<option value="'+ item.id +'">'+ $label +'</option>');  

           });
         },
         error: function() {
           alert("Error is occured");
         }
   });
});
```

Comment: chek #27521643 for a comment would help you with your $label. By the way your $label is not assigned.

Answer (score -1):

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script>
 function __highlight(s, t) {
        var matcher = new RegExp("(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(t) + ")", "ig");
         return s.replace(matcher, "<strong>$1</strong>");
               }
    $(document).ready(
              function() {
                 $("#suggest").autocomplete(
                  {
                    source : function(request, response) 
                {
                    $.ajax({
                            url : 'URL',
                            dataType : 'json',
                            data : { term : request.term },
                            success : function(data) 
                                        {
                                            //alert(data[0].title);
                                            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                                        //alert(item);
                             return {                                                           
                    label : __highlight(item.title, request.term),
                   value : item.title
                        };
                                                                                }));
                                        }
                        });
                },
        minLength : 3,
        select : function(event, ui) 
                {
                    if(ui.item){
                        $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
                        }
                        //submit the form
                    $(event.target.form).submit();
                }
        }).keydown(function(e) {
                                    if (e.keyCode === 13) 
                                    {
                                        $("#search_form").trigger('submit');
                                    }
                                }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) 
                                                                    {
                            return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(
                            $("<a></a>").html(item.label)).appendTo(ul);
                                                                    };
        });
               </script>
```